# select Details fro where condition sub query getting error

Tags: sql

I am having two tables. APP_REVIEWREPLAY , APP_USERREVIEW . i am using sub query from different table by where condition , in that the sub query is returning double values , so i am getting error. My error is

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

select * from APP_REVIEWREPLAY where RID=(select RID from APP_USERREVIEW where HALLID=7095)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use a join

```
select r.* 
from APP_REVIEWREPLAY r
JOIN APP_USERREVIEW u on u.rid = r.rid
where u.HALLID=7095
```

or the `in` clause

```
select * 
from APP_REVIEWREPLAY 
where RID in (select RID from APP_USERREVIEW where HALLID=7095)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the IN clause

```
select * 
from APP_REVIEWREPLAY 
where RID IN (select RID from APP_USERREVIEW where HALLID=7095)
```